# Getting the text from the Element -- exclude the text of inner element

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I've a HTML as Below

```
<div class="someClass">
     LNAME, FNAME MNAME
    <a class="button" onclick="#">This is Button</a>
</div>
```

I want to get the text inside the `div.someClass` i.e `LNAME, FNAME MNAME`.

But I'm getting following

```
LNAME, FNAME MNAME 
This is Button
```

I'm using `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.someClass")).getText();`

I'm aware that above code is giving me the text of `div.someClass` element as a whole.

How can I extract the value of just `div.someClass` but not inner element. For example I've given, I want output as

```
LNAME, FNAME MNAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//a[@class='button']/preceding-sibling::text()
```

Answer (score 1):

[getText()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29) - as per definition - Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, **including sub-elements**, without any leading or trailing whitespace.

For removing text from sub-elements you have to handle it yourself, like explained below:

```
public String getTopElementText(By by)
{
   WebElement topElement = driver.findElement(by);
   String originalText = topElement.getText();

   // get all child elements who has innerText and stringlength is greater than 0
   List<WebElement> children = topElement.findElements(By.xpath("*[string-length(text()) > 0]"))

   for(WebElement element :  children)
      orginalText = originalText.replace(element.getText(), "");

  return originalText;
}
```